# Directing browsers without H264 support to flash with video.js

Tags: video.js

I'm setting up video.js and would like to use a single video encoding format (H264) in order to save space (it would save over 50% in my case). video.js falls back to a flash player when HTML5 video isn't possible, but I'd like it to also fall back when H264 support isn't present too (in Firefox, for example). Is there some way to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything. That is what will happen.

It works [here](http://misterben.me/videojs/mp4.html), for example. Do you have a URL where it's not working for you?

Comment: Do you have an example of this? In my testing I get the message "Specified "type" of "video/mp4" is not supported." in FireFox so it looks like I do need to do something in order to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

You could try detecting support for that format directly if you needed to - although I agree, it should fallback to Flash automatically.

http://diveintohtml5.info/detect.html#video-formats gives an example of detecting support for h264